# Change value of td when pass to servlet

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets

Im looping to a table,and giving them names or id,but when i need to get a value from

```
<select>
<option>Yes</option>
<option>No</option>
</select>

var $tds = $(this).find('td select');
$tds.eq(0).prop('name','support' + ctr);

if($tds.val() == "Yes"){
// I want the value to pass in servlet is true else false but dont know the right syntax
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with "Ajax"?

Comment: @undefined no sir, T.T

Comment: There are many related questions on SO, like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16067592/javascript-jquery-to-servlet-communication. Regarding the question, I usually pass a boolean value, 0 for failure and 1 for success. `var param = $tds.val() == "Yes" ? 1 : 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Checkout http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

To build on your code:

```
if($tds.val() == "Yes"){
  // Initialize an ajax POST request to servlet some.php with someData
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: someData // Put your data here
  })
  // When done, alert a message indicating the data was saved.
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
}
```

You can also catch and handle possible errors in making the request to the servlet.